# External login issues due to WWW-Authentication

Tags: authentication, login

How do i change settings so that external users, with their own Sharepoint sites are prompted to enter credentials for our site. Currently the users are presented with an error messgae stating "your web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header fiel that the web server is not configured to accept"

Answer (score 1):

can you refer to this and see if it works for you:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q253667&sd=tech

hope it helps :)